# Can't find template for view's row - Drupal

Tags: templates, drupal-7, rows, drupal-views

I have a view created that displays content type "Gallery images".

I can style this content type in `node--gallery_images.tpl.php`, but this template is for both gallery images and gallery images in view. I want galleries in view stylize differently than individual gallery.

- **Display output**: **views-view.tpl.php**, views-view--gallery.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--page.tpl.php, views-view--gallery--page.tpl.php
- **Style output**: **views-view-unformatted.tpl.php**, views-view-unformatted--gallery.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--page.tpl.php, views-view-unformatted--gallery--page.tpl.php
- **Row style output**: .tpl.php, --gallery.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --page.tpl.php, --gallery--page.tpl.php

I was trying all possible combinations like `views-view--gallery--page.tpl.php, views-view-row--gallery--page.tpl.php` and so on, including `--gallery--page.tpl.php` but can't find the right file name. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: I suppose your view uses "content" display type instead of "fields" with "teaser" view mode set, right ? Did you tried changing the view mode for the  results ? Or you can use the same node template but switch the view mode inside of the file (**node--gallery_images.tpl.php**) to have a different node layout.

Comment: No, why should I change the view mode?